# How do I parse this json data in view blade? Output [{"...":...}]

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

I am trying to display the maximum value of an attribute in a table

my controller

```
$member = DB::table('member')
->select(DB::raw('MAX(code) as code'))  
->where('status', '=', "No")->get();
return view('member.index', compact('member'));
```

Currently this is my view

```
{{ $member }}
```

And this is the output

[{"code":14101234}]

I wanted to display something like this

14101234

I've tried using json_decode but the result remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `$member` is a array of object you are getting in view. 
So you can fetch a object key by `->` operator. you can fetch code like this. since you are doing `->get()`, so it will return array of object.

```
@foreach($member as $m)
  {{ $m->code }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 2):

You receive a collection there, so you will have to do

```
@foreach($member as $item)

    {!! $item->code !!}

@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

$member is a collection object.You can iterate through it to get the value in your view.
example:  (in view.blade.php)

```
@foreach($member as $individual)
     {{$individual->code}}
@endforeach
```

this would give you the value as you want